# how do you make a Theme switcher using Jquery and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to make a theme swither using jQuery, I see the example made in the docs of the jQuery [mobile page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/pages-themes/theme-b.html), but it's exhaustive as it dublicates the same page but with different theme swatch as a result it affects only one page in the App, I want a theme switcher that affects all the pages of the App, thanks.

Comment: Why not just store the theme they chose in a cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using jQuery UI and their `themeswitcher` - http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/ThemeSwitcher

It works great on our internal site.  If nothing else, look at the way they do it and you should be able to come up with your own customer solution rather easily.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps storing the selected theme (local storage/cookie) and using jQuery to grab that value and add a style element to the page?

Comment: i have a nice idea, i can make say a div with an Id(links) contains three anchor elements corresponding to the diff themes, these elements contains a (data-theme) attribute, when the user clicks any link a function will replaces all the (data-theme) attributes in the page with the one in the clicked element, but how i can do that with javaScript?

Comment: using jQuery attr() you can replace any attribute of any element, even if it's non-standard. $("#mydiv").attr("data-theme", themenamevariable);

Answer (score 0):

Use a session variable to determine which CSS to include.